# The token was issued in the future - Laravel Firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using react.js as fron-end & laravel for creating API's for web app

in react.js i'm using firebase to get `googleAuth` then sending it Laravel App
in Laravel i'm using `"kreait/laravel-firebase": "^5.7",`

`SocialRegister` is working fine for me in Laravel side

When i'm trying to log user in using the code below

```
  try {
        /** @var FirebaseAuth $firebaseAuth */
        $firebaseAuth = app(FirebaseAuth::class);

        // Verify the ID token
        $verifiedIdToken = $firebaseAuth->verifyIdToken($request->access_token);

        // Extract claims from the verified ID token
        $uid = $verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('sub');
        $userEmail = $verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('email');

        // Check if the user already exists in your database
        $existingUser = AppUser::where('email', $userEmail)->first();

        if ($existingUser) {
            // User already exists, return an error or handle it as per your requirements
            return $this->sendresponse('false', 'user already exists', null);
        }


        $user = AppUser::create([
            "email" => $request->email,
            "name" => $request->name,
            "access_token" => $uid, // Save Firebase UID for future reference
        ]);


        // Return success response
        return $this->sendresponse('true', 'user registered successfully', ['user' => $user]);
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        // Handle registration errors
        return $this->sendresponse('false', 'registration error', $e->getMessage());
    }
```

`

Then i'm getting this error

> The value 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...' is not a verified ID token: - - The token was issued in the future

I even tried changing `timezone` of my laravel app but it didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when there is a clock skew between the signing server (Firebase) and the verifying server (your server or local computer).

In that case, you can provide a leeway in seconds to allow a token to be expired:

```php
$leewayInSeconds = 360; // 5 minutes

$verifiedIdToken = $firebaseAuth
    ->verifyIdToken($request->access_token, $leewayInSeconds);
```